# How to get location value from json value?

Tags: php, json

First i use this link for get longtitude and longtitude from city name

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=usa,califonia,Los%20Angeles&key={API-KEY}&language=EN
```

...........................................................................................................................................................

When load this url i get this json format.

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Los Angeles",
               "short_name" : "Los Angeles",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Los Angeles County",
               "short_name" : "Los Angeles County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "California",
               "short_name" : "CA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Los Angeles, CA, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 34.3373061,
                  "lng" : -118.1552891
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 33.7036519,
                  "lng" : -118.6681759
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 34.0522342,
               "lng" : -118.2436849
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 34.3373061,
                  "lng" : -118.1552891
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 33.7036519,
                  "lng" : -118.6681759
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJE9on3F3HwoAR9AhGJW_fL-I",
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I want to get `location ==> lat` = 34.0522342 and `location ==> lng` = -118.2436849 from json format.

Then i use this code.

```
<?php
$url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=usa,califonia,Los%20Angeles&key={API-KEY}&language=EN';
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$json_data = json_decode($json, true);

$location_lat =  $json_data['results']['location']['lat'];
$location_lng =  $json_data['results']['location']['lng'];

echo $location_lat;
echo $location_lng;
?>
```

But i not get any data ? How can i do ?

Comment: Where do you see `data` in the response? Your path is wrong. Also, you're missing a `]` after 'data', so that your syntax is incorrect also. Just `print_r($json_data);` and build your way from there on if you can't do it by heart.

Comment: And where is `location` in the data? (under `geometry`)

Comment: @ Nigel Ren--- `            "location" : {
               "lat" : 34.0522342,
               "lng" : -118.2436849
            },`

Comment: @Nigel Ren -- location is out side from geometry

Answer (score 1):

If you get the layers of data correct, then you should use...

```
$location_lat =  $json_data['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
$location_lng =  $json_data['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];

echo $location_lat.PHP_EOL;
echo $location_lng;
```

Which outputs...

```
34.0522342
-118.2436849
```

Answer (score 0):

you can edit to

```
$location_lat =  $json_data['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
$location_lng =  $json_data['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
```